# Golang image iptc metadata

Tags: image, go, metadata, meta, iptc

I need to get the meta data, especially the iptc meta data from the uploaded files on the server.

I have found two packages I can import, but both of them require the "libiptcdata" libary. It should not be a problem, but after I installed the libary with brew, as it is written on both of the packages page, and typed go get "https://github.com/Melraidin/iptc" (for example, one of the two packages I wanted to use), I got the following error:

`../../github.com/Melraidin/iptc/main.go:10:10: fatal error: libiptcdata/iptc-data.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libiptcdata/iptc-data.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.`

The error is real, the file is really is not there, but how then it could work at anyone else? I found these 2 packages suggestion of using on a few page.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't know about brew, but under Linux you would have to install both `libiptcdata` (which contains the actual library) and `libiptcdata-dev` (which contains the source code). Maybe that's the reason why the `iptc-data.h` file is not present?

Comment: yepp, file does not exist where the code looking for it
if you check for example this: https://github.com/Melraidin/iptc there is how to install it with brew, and they do not say anything about the dev, BUT thank you, and I will start tomorrow with trying your suggestion.

Comment: it was a part of the solution, but with, it still does not worked yet, now it is, will write how.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have removed the brew installed "libiptcdata" libary, than installed the following libaries:

"libiptcdata0"
"libiptcdata0-dev"
"python-iptcdata"

with these three, the "go get" is managed to run, and could continue working on the original problem...